# Is it better to send Systrem.Drawing.Bitmap converted to bytes when using NetNamedPipeBinding?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soa

I've got a WCF service which accepts an image as input (as System.Drawing.Bitmap). It is executing on the same machine and is using the **NetNamedPipeBinding**. Currently the service interface is defined this way:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DoWork(Bitmap image);
}
```

It works just fine. But I am not sure how the Bitmap is serialized and I don't know whether it's better in terms of performance to just get the image bytes and send them instead of relying on the .net serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `Bitmap` class *is* serializable, `DataContractSerializer` supports it serialization.
See "[Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx)".

Comment: Yes, and my service is working. It wouldn't if it was not supported by the `DataContractSerializer`. So your answer isn't very helpful. The question is whether it will be better to send just the bytes. This was in the question description rather than in the title. I just edited the title.

Comment: "whether it will be better to send just the bytes" - so, what is serialization, from you point? :)

Comment: I mean to manually do it. E.g. that way the `DataContractSerializer` won't have to use Reflection to check whether the class is supported. Which will speed things up.

Comment: Do you have any performance problems? If yes, than why you've decided, than they're related to serialization? If no, than why are you trying to do premature optimizations? Comparing to data transfer across network, serialization is a very fast process. Usually, serialization is a last place for optimizations in WCF.

Comment: Yes, I have. I decided so because I excluded other parts of the equation (while I admit I still may have missed something). And because when I was searching for solutions some people have been sending the bytes manually instead of relying on .NET Bitmap serialization. So that's why I decided to ask and find out which is a better practice.